# How to stop partition column appearing last in a SELECT * output, in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql, impala

In Apache Hive, I'm trying to copy specific rows from one table to a second table that's identical apart from an additional string column (which I'm calling "report-type") at the end of the second table. Both tables are partitioned by a string field called 'dt' which has a date e.g. "2022-08-04". When I try and copy a row from table 1 to table 2, the data is inserted into table 2 with report-type and dt swapped, because the partition column seems to be forcibly listed last.

E.g. `INSERT INTO table2 SELECT *, 'some_report_type' FROM table1 WHERE <some criteria>;`

gives all the data in table2 in the correct columns apart from report-type is e.g. "2022-08-04" and dt is e.g. "2022-08-04"

Is there any way around this?

Two solutions I can see are recreate the table without the partitioning (ideally want to avoid) and just have dt as a regular non-partition column, or alternatively specify each of the columns in a column list in the query, but not sure if this would force "dt" to not be the last column, and the main issue with that is I have 830 columns to specify individually.

Thanks

Comment: You're right. Remove partition from table1 or mention all columns in proper order in select stmt. I assume table2 is unpartitioned. Use metadata table to fetch the column names.

Comment: @KoushikRoy Thanks. Both tables are partitioned by string field "dt", does that affect your answer at all?

Comment: no, it doesnt. Only that sql in your question is wrong...